I need to decide on placement for PDU's and Cable management for server racks
I need to decide on placement of vertical PDUs and cable managment for server racks in a new colo cage.
Each of the servers have a cabel managment arm to allow the servers to be slid forward on its rails without disconnecting any fiber, copper or power cables from back of the servers. The arms are basicaly folded accross the back of the server and when you slide the servers forwared it extends into the the rack cabel managment arm
Alls cables need to be placed in the arms to allow the forward movement.
My question is should I place PDUs and cable managment on only 1 side of the rear of the rack to facilitate entry into the cable managment arm?
What do you all recomend.

These days, people don't use cable management arms because they impact airflow and thermal conditions.
The use case is super narrow for something that is not clustered, but needs to be serviced while powered on.
Also see: https://serverfault.com/a/429563/13325

Hi, That is more true with 1 U servers. I have mostly 2 and 4 U with lots of cables.
The servers have multiple VMs so shutting them down for maintence is not realy an option.

Can you share the specific maintenance situation that you're envisioning where you need to work inside of the server on a hot-swappable component while the entire system is powered on?
